# Can't log in from terminal

Tags: authentication, pam

I have a server with a hosting provider (OVH).  I've never had any trouble logging in via SSH, but I use RSA authentication, so I'm not sure if I could actually get in with a password.  However, when attempting to log in via iKVM (IPMI), I always get a `Login incorrect` error.  I've tried both my own account and root; neither work, no matter how many times I update the passwords.  `/etc/shadow` looks fine; I see valid hashes for both accounts.  Here's what shows up in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Apr 18 18:12:08 mc-0 login[5258]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=paul
Apr 18 18:12:12 mc-0 login[5258]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'paul', Authentication failure
```

I've tried other terminals (tty2, etc.), too, with no luck.  X isn't installed, so there's no GUI, just a CLI.

I don't see anything unusual in `/etc/pam.d/*`, but I don't know my way around those files too well.  `/etc/securetty` has the `console`, some X displays, `tty{1..63}`, `ttyS{0..5}`, a bunch of other obscure `tty{something}{number}` entries, some stuff for LXC, and `duart{0,1}`.

Comment: Have you tried directly ssh'ing into the server and using password authentication? If that fails and you know your user/password is correct there should be a directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config that is something like `PasswordAuthentication yes` Which could be commented out, or set to No. This would block all programs using ssh from logging in via password.

Comment: @BrianSizemore I currently have `PasswordAuthentication` set to `no`, and I'd like to keep it that way.  SSH is working fine; it's direct terminal access that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using caps-lock for part of my password.  I'm used to caps-lock lagging a bit on Linux, but it was lagging a lot more than normal and generally being unreliable over iKVM.

And I was all ready to dive into the PAM source code...